# i want to miss the keyboard. when i move to next page

Tags: reactjs, popup

```
const submitBtnHandler = async () => {
    if (isValid && detailAddress.length) {
      await inputRef.current?.blur();
      hidePopup();
      setRegisterState({info_detail: detailAddress});
      navigate(nextUrl);
    } else {
      setIsClicked(true);
      return;
    }
  };
```

this works when i click a button.
my expectation is

1. keyboard is missing
2. hidepopup
3. setRegisterState
4. move to nextUrl

but it works like this:
but when it moves to nextUrl keyboard is not missing, so nextUrl page's size is containing the keyboard.

i think, missing the keyboard and move to nextUrl is working at the same time

what can i do?

i don't want to useing setTimeout.